# ActiveAdmin Giving `` arguments (2 for 1)`` ArgumentError When Updating Any Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

### The Problem:

When trying to update a resource through the ActiveAdmin interface I am receiving a:

```
ArgumentError in Admin::FoobarController#update 
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

I have recently upgraded my app to Rails 4 and am using:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

### Further Details

I am not overriding controller behavior in anyway that I am aware of.  Creating and deleting resources works.
I have about 8 resources and they all behave the same way.

[Link to issue opened on github](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/3153)

#### Full Trace:

```
ArgumentError in Admin::AddressesController#update
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Rails.root: /home/vagrant/foo
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:14:in `assign_attributes'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-f65e7cd6425b/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:176:in `update_resource'
inherited_resources (1.4.1) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:45:in `update'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:463:in `_run__4531637651338111969__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.8.1.221) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.8.1.221) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.8.1.221) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.8.1.221) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:45:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3598748950198072584__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:58:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
airbrake (3.1.6) lib/airbrake/rack.rb:41:in `call'
airbrake (3.1.6) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
puma (2.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:490:in `handle_request'
puma (2.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:361:in `process_client'
puma (2.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
puma (2.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `call'
puma (2.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ZAy1C6DDowo5aqy1b6GK0NA00iGL75jNi33vDEn11uo=",
 "address"=>{"street_number"=>"001",
 "street_name"=>"Category Solar Testing",
 "city"=>"Antigua",
 "state"=>"AL",
 "zipcode"=>"01234"},
 "commit"=>"Update Address",
 "id"=>"264"}
```

Comment: Seems like issue, try to post this to `active_admin` [issues](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'm getting the same issue moving from protected_attributes to strong_parameters.

Comment: I have fixed this for myself by forking and modifying.  That said, I have not made a formal pull request to active_admin and thus won't answer my question.  Here is a link to the issue that I opened with my explanation of what I did:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/3153#issuecomment-44385174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced this issue and it turned out to be legacy code in the ActiveAdmin initializer that I had put in when on RoR 3.2 for mass-assignment protection. Since I am now on RoR4, this is now handled by strong parameters.

One of the commenters in the issue mentioned by @Michael Pell in the comments to his original question, [mentions the fix](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3153#issuecomment-61963923)

In my particular case, I had code originally put in following the advice fom [this blog post](http://ejholmes.io/2012/04/22/handling-mass-assignment-with-active-admin.html), so I had to remove from `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`:

```
moduleActiveAdmin
  # REMOVE FROM HERE
  class BaseController
    def role_given?
      current_user.role
    end
    def as_role
      { as: current_admin_user.role.downcase.to_sym }
    end
  end
  # TO HERE

  # More initializer code down here
  # ...
end
```